# WhatsApp отправка сообщений через Chat-API

Tags: php, api, whatsapp

Доброго дня!
Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли сейчас живой и работающий вариант передачи сообщений с сайта в WhatsApp?

Chat-API уже не поддерживается?